# how to replace text inside a div using a for loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I doing wrong here?  Not well versed in js, so assuming I'm doing my for loop wrong.

```html
<div class="date-widget">
  hello1
</div>
<div class="date-widget">
  hello2
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var utcInstances = $('.date-widget');

  for (i = 0; i < utcInstances.length; i++) {
    utcInstances[i].text("new text");
  }

});
```

error:

> TypeError: utcInstances[i].text is not a function

http://jsfiddle.net/0jkwasqc/1/

Comment: use utcInstances[i].textContent = "new text";

Comment: When you index a jQuery collection, the values are DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: You don't need a loop, just do `utcInstances.text("new text");` if you want to give them all the same text.

Comment: they will all be unique and dynamic names, I just put "new text" in the fiddle for brevity, my fault there

Comment: `utcInstances.eq(i).text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's jQuery that you'll need more practice with. Specifically when you want to loop through a jQuery collection, you should use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Each item in the collection is a DOM object, not a jQuery object, so you'll have to wrap it before calling `.text` on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var utcInstances = $('.date-widget');

  utcInstances.each( (i, instance) => {
    $(instance).text("new text");  // Wrap instance DOM object into a jQuery object before calling .text
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-widget">
  hello1
</div>
<div class="date-widget">
  hello2
</div>
```